# How to create registry key that contains "/"

Tags: powershell, escaping

So I want to create a registry key in:

```
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 128/128
```

How do I do this in PowerShell? I tried:

```
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 128/128"
```

However PowerShell doesn't like the `RC2 128/128` path bit. Its throwing a `System ArgumentException`.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're seeing a bug / design limitation, still present as of PowerShell 7.2.3: `/` is also treated as a path separator, in addition to ``\``. While this interchangeable separator use is helpful with _file-system_ paths, it causes problems in registry paths, given that `/` is a legal character in key names. See [GitHub issue #5536](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5536#issuecomment-346917545]. Escaping `/` with `\`` doesn't work, unfortunately. You'll probably need to use .NET APIs directly.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're running **.NET 4+**, you can try using [`RegistryKey.CreateSubKey` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.createsubkey?view=net-6.0):

```
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.CreateSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 128/128')
$key.Close()
Test-Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 128/128' # => Should be `$true`
```

Needles to say, **PowerShell must be running as Administrator to create a new key in HKLM**.